# Different Image on each Mainmenu entry in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming

there is a Logo and a variable picture in the header of my design. This picture depends on the current page.

Is there a plugin or even a build in setting, where i can configure this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [this module](http://drupal.org/project/dynamic_banner), which seems to do exactly that.

Comment: Ok this seems nice, but do i have to set a new image on every node?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve. The module supports wildcard, so you should be able to set images for several nodes based on path.

Comment: Ok. Thank.
Is there a open issue with the Textfield? My image is only displayed if i fill in the textfield.

Comment: Well, you'll have to go to the modules documentation and/or issue queue to know about specifics concerning its usage. Good luck.